# What was the first game to use humorous progress updates?

Tags: history

I've recently downloaded Futurama: Worlds of Tomorrow on my phone, and I noticed it has a progress bar with humorous messages in it (it usually loads fast enough for only two messages to appear). Two much older games I can remember that had the same feature were Sim City 2000 ("reticulating splines") from 1993, and Afterlife released in 1996. Afterlife even had such messages as "Bored with loading, restarting" which would temporarily set the progress back to the beginning without affecting the real load time, and I believe it also had a mirror image progress bar that increased to the left.

What was the first game (or other software) to display the loading progress in a humorous way?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited to Arqade?

Comment: Probably the second game to display loading progress.

Comment: I'll bet it was something on the C64: given that writing your own fast loader was pretty much obligatory for commercial titles on both tape and disk probably within a year of its introduction, you can bet that somebody somewhere put a joke into theirs.

Comment: I think a question like this (first game to do X) is considered off topic on Arqade, @LyricLy

Comment: As per https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/530/278 I've voted to close as Too Broad.

Comment: If you're thinking of moving it to Arqade, just brace yourself. They are very unwelcoming.